# Get OpenSea profile data using Google Apps Script into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, opensea

I am trying to get Twitter link from [OpenSea profile](https://opensea.io/0xe7dAe42Dee2BB6C1ef3c65e68d3E605faBcA875d) using the following Google Apps Script sample code:

```
function getTwitterLink() {

  var url = "https://opensea.io/0xe7dAe42Dee2BB6C1ef3c65e68d3E605faBcA875d";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      
  var regex = /https:\/\/twitter.com\/[^"']+/;
  var match = regex.exec(response);
  
  if (match && match.length > 0) {
    var twitterLink = match[0];
    Logger.log("Twitter Link: " + twitterLink);
    return twitterLink;
  } else {
    Logger.log("Twitter Link not found.");
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the profile, you can find the link embedded in the Twitter logo on right most side:

[image: Twitter Link]

However, it gives the following **error** when it runs:

> Exception: Request failed for https://opensea.io returned code 403.
> Truncated server response:   
> Just a moment...
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full
> response)

I think this is because I need to use API key to get this Twitter link. So I reviewed [OpenSea API Documentation](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/api-overview). But unable to find any relevant endpoint. I would really appreciate it if you can guide me to get this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I looked at the documentation, I found the endpoint to get Twitter account information, so here is the proposed script:

```
function getTwitterLink() {

 var url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/user/0xe7dAe42Dee2BB6C1ef3c65e68d3E605faBcA875d";

 var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-API-KEY': 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 var payload = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
 var twitterLink = "https://twitter.com/" + payload.account.twitter_username;
 console.log(twitterLink)
 }
```

Let me know if it helps.