# Getting Twiitter account (Verified, Non-Verified) information from OpenSea using API and Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping, opensea

This is the continuation of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76709871/get-opensea-profile-data-using-google-apps-script-into-google-sheets/76713219#76713219), [Roomi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12736831/roomi) proposed a following solution:

```
function getTwitterLink() {

 var url = "https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/user/0xe7dAe42Dee2BB6C1ef3c65e68d3E605faBcA875d";

 var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-API-KEY': 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 var payload = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
 var twitterLink = "https://twitter.com/" + payload.account.twitter_username;
 console.log(twitterLink)
 }
```

It works perfectly when a verified Twitter account is connected with OpenSea user profile but it does not get the information **(Twitter profile link)** of the non-verified Twitter account. Following are the screenshots which I am talking about:

[image: Non-Verified] [image: verified]

> Non-Verified Wallet Address:
> https://opensea.io/0xed3c3bffcf147850406d0e58ce4f4ebd2b5cd96c

> Verified Wallet Address:
> https://opensea.io/0xe7dAe42Dee2BB6C1ef3c65e68d3E605faBcA875d

The script does not get Twitter information from the left screenshot (Non-Verified) and works well with the right screenshot (verified account). Any idea how to get information **(Twitter profile link)** from both types of accounts, can we directly scrape information from OpenSea user profiles? Thank you